# Simple vectorial sum not evaluating in Maple?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, numerical-methods, vectors, maple

I'm having a stupid trouble with this trivial code in *Maple*.  The output is, well, ... stupid !  I'm asking *Maple* to do a vectorial sum and substraction of 5 cross products, and what I get is silly :  a sum of vectors, but it doesn't give the total vector !  What the hell !?

```
with(linalg):
with(DEtools):

ly := 9.4607*10^15:
M0 := 1.99*10^30:

M1 := 2.20*M0:
M2 := 2.00*M0:
M3 := 1.50*M0:
M4 := 3.00*M0:

r1 := [-3, 3, 0]*ly:
r2 := [0, -2, 0]*ly:
r3 := [1, 2, 0]*ly:
r4 := [6, 4, 0]*ly:

v1 := [25, 15, 0]*10^3:
v2 := [20, -20, 0]*10^3:
v3 := [-5, -25, 0]*10^3:
v4 := [15, 0, 0]*10^3:

Mtot := M1 + M2 + M3 + M4:

rcm := (M1*r1 + M2*r2 + M3*r3 + M4*r4)/Mtot:
vcm := (M1*v1 + M2*v2 + M3*v3 + M4*v4)/Mtot:

Ltot := crossprod(r1, M1*v1) + crossprod(r2, M2*v2) + crossprod(r3, M3*v3) + crossprod(r4, M4*v4) - crossprod(rcm, Mtot*vcm);
```

I'm not a strong user of Maple, so I may have done a simple mistake somewhere, but I really don't see what and where.  So what is wrong with this *Maple* code ?

Comment: Join us here http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107315/maple

Comment: Why the down vote ?  Downvoting without explanations is counter-productive.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using a very old version of Maple, you should load the `LinearAlgebra` package instead of `linalg`.  Then, you need to form Vectors using angle <> brackets instead of square [] brackets which give you a Lists.

Once you have Vectors, you can form cross products with the &x operator.  e.g.

```
with(LinearAlgebra):
r1 := <-3, 3, 0>*ly;
v1 := <25, 15, 0>*10^3;
r1 &x (M1*v1);
```

(note that you do need parenthesis around the second operand of the cross product - due to its precedence relative to *)

Comment: I don't understand these changes.  I have several other codes with vectors defined as **[ ... ]** and the **crossprod** command, and they are all working fine.  My code above is able to do properly the cross products, but it doesn't add up the results.  This is the problem I need to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that adding a simple command does the trick :

```
evalm(Ltot);
```

Simple and neat !

Comment: This is the right solution if you are using a very old version of Maple.  In newer versions, evalm along with all the commands in the linalg package are deprecated, you'll be better off switching over to LinearAlgebra and the newer Vector and Matrix constructors.

Comment: @JPMay, I'm using Maple 13 on my personal computer, and Maple 15 at work.  Is this THAT old ?

Comment: You should be using LinearAlgebra commands then.  By very old, I mean before Maple 6.

Comment: I don't get any "deprecated" message in Maple 13 and 15.  Why the new cryptic way of defining vectors with "<...>" that can be confused with "lower" and "greater" ?  The "[...]" fits perfectly my needs.

Comment: The fact that you had to ask the original question give the answer to why these commands have been deprecated -- they are listed as deprecated on their help pages.
 
Angle brackets are a really standard notation in many places.  They are typeset differently from greater than and less than symbols in the Maple user interface.  The square brackets construct lists which are an entirely different datastructure from Vectors.  If you can make a Vector from lists using the command: Vector([1,2,3]);

Comment: In *Mathematica* (which I much prefer over *Maple* anytime), vectors are just a special case of a list with three components, and everything is defined like matrices, with curvy brackets : {...}.  I didn't got a choice in using *Maple* in the case above, because of my job place...

Comment: I have extensive experience in both systems (and many others) and can say that there are a lot of really good reasons to use the immutable List data structure for vectors and matrices (it makes many things very slow). I agree that it makes the system superficially user friendly, however.

Comment: JP May likely meant to write, "...there are a lot of really good reasons to *not* use the immutable List data structure for vectors and matrices (it makes many things very slow)". A list structure in Maple is immutable, in that assigning to any entry of a list produces a full copy as a wholly new structure, and so is an inefficient way to compute. The deprecated lowercase `vector` (for `linalg`) is implemented using Maple's mutable `table`. But as seen, using `linalg` requires using `evalm`. The `Vector` of `LinearAlgebra` is mutable and doesn't require using `evalm`.